# Java Iterator implementation compile error: does not override abstract method remove()

Tags: java, iterator

Why do i get the following compile error:

`LRIterator is not abstract and does not override abstract method remove() in java.util.Iterator`

Note, the implementation is for a linked list

```
public Iterator iterator()
{
    return new LRIterator() ;
}

private class LRIterator implements Iterator
{
    private DLLNode place ;
    private LRIterator()
    {
        place = first ;
    }
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return (place != null) ;
    }
    public Object next()
    {
        if (place == null)  throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return place.elem ;
        place = place.succ ;
    }

}
```

Comment: because `LRIterator is not abstract and does not override abstract method remove()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Java 8

In Java 8 the [`remove` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) has a default implementation that throws `UnsupportedOperatorException` so in Java 8 the code compiles fine.

---

### Java 7 and below

Because the `Iterator` interface has a method called `remove()`, which you must implement in order to say that you have implemented the `Iterator` interface.

**If you *don't* implement it the class is "missing" a method implementation, which is only okay for *abstract* classes, i.e., classes that defer implementation of some methods to subclasses.**

The documentation may seem confusing as it says that `remove()` is an "optional operation". This only means that you don't have to actually be able to remove elements from the underlying implementation, but you still need to implement the method. If you don't want to do actually remove anything from the underlying collection you implement it like this:

```
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Comment: Just an addendum: Eclipse doesn't seem to complain about the method, either, even in Java 7 mode; one should keep that in mind if writing code that's supposed to compile both inside and outside of the IDE.

Comment: If Eclipse doesn't complain about not overriding `remove` then you have not configured it correctly. The IDE and javac accepts/rejects the exact same set of programs, unless you've stumbled across a compiler bug, but that's very rare for simple programs such as this.

Answer (score 3):

You must implement [`remove`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) because it is part of the contract defined by the [`Iterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface.

If you don't want to implement it then make it throw an exception instead:

```
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

...because you're not providing a definition for `remove()`, and `Iterator` is an interface, so you *must* supply a definition for all of its functions for any concrete implementation.

You can, however, add a method that throws an exception if you don't want to support the functionality:

```
public void remove(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterator is an interface which means that you should implement all methods

```
public interface Iterator<E> {
    boolean hasNext();
    E next();
    void remove();
}
```

hasNext() and next() you already have so just add remove() method

If you haven't any idea just throw appropriate exception:

```
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a

```
public Object remove() {
  throw new RuntimeException ("I'm not going to implement it!!!");
}
```

Comment: is it void really? embarrassing :)